# Coldfusion server VERY slow page loads

Tags: iis, coldfusion

I inherited a windows server 2003 coldfusion 7 server a few weeks ago.  Today a network cable was unplugged by accident from the server.  On plugging it back in, pages were NOT loading at all.  Rather, we were receiving a generic coldfusion error page.  After restarting IIS several times and coldfusion even more than that, we finally got pages to start loading.  However, the loading is extremely slow (30+ seconds) on pages that used to load instantly.  Loading through the local network (IE localhost/cfide/administrator) does nothing to help the load speed.

I am not familiar with IIS or Coldfusion (We're in the process of migrating this to Linux/PHP), so this is all new territory to me.  I'm hoping someone may have experienced this issue in the past and can help me solve it.

I'm happy to provide any additional information that might be necessary....I'm just not sure what information you might need in order to help.

**UPDATE** - Have discovered that immediately after restarting IIS, a page or two will load immediately before going back to the slowness.  Have also investigated the coldfusion logs which mention losing the connection to a datasource.  Coincidentally, we are in the process of moving our MySQL database to a remote server right now.  But surely this wouldn't cause the pages to hang forever..?

Comment: Did you start moving the MySQL database before or after the NIC was unplugged?

Comment: Fixed the problem.  It turns out coldfusion does not like accessing a database outside our network.  Moved it back inside and pages are again loading instantly.

No idea WHY this froze our server, but it's fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

I would reboot first of all, there may have been something affected by the network outage such as defaulting to an alternate DNS or AD server or other impact.

Comment: Ben - Rebooting is generally the solution of ***LAST*** resort: It may fix the problem, but in doing so it destroys all state information and usually makes it hard (if not impossible) to find the root cause.  Certainly an emergency situation may warrant this approach, but it shouldn't be a "first of all" solution.

Comment: We have already tried the reboot thing because this is semi-emergency.  It didn't help at all.  I did discover something new, but I will place this as an update to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you do not have extra NICs that have no cable but are not disabled. Windows can assign a private IP address to those NICs and cause IIS to respond more slowly because internally it is still trying to send to both the now valid NIC and the unplugged NICs.

Comment: I checked and there is only one NIC in the machine.

Answer (score 0):

if you turn on debugging for your IP address, you can see what parts of the page take the longest to load.

also, have you looked at the server statistics (processor usage, memory usage, disk latency if you have access to that info)?